# Do I need to define Solidity version on Remix IDE?

Tags: solidity, remix

How do I define Solidity version on Remix IDE?

Not sure if I need to define the version.

Comment: You can specify it in the `compiler` tab. At the top there's a select box with Solidity version. Although I think Remix tries to set the correct one automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the compiler version in the `Solidity Compiler` tab (3rd icon on the left).

And, of course, you also need to include the version in your solidity source files, like this: `pragma solidity 0.x.x`. [More on that here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/layout-of-source-files.html#pragmas)